# Error : You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list

Tags: raspberry-pi, installation

I'm trying to install Stellarium on Raspberry Pi. I used

```
apt-get build-dep stellarium
```

When I try and do this I get the error:

> E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Uncomment the line `"deb-sr http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/jessie main contrib non-free rpi"`